# Treatments for the Plague

Tags: medicine, early-medieval

We have all heard of the [Plague Doctors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plague_doctor), but is there any information on the Treatments that they offered the sick? I have looked at the work of 
[Guy de Chauliac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_de_Chauliac) but I have been unable to find a copy of his work that isn't in Latin and my Latin is far too rusty. :)

Comment: If you are using an online version of his work, you can try to use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx#la) to translate it. It isn't the best, but it might do.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this BBC publication](http://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/ks3/history/middle_ages/the_black_death/revision/5/) the medieval plague treatments included:

- cooked onions
- ten-year-old treacle
- arsenic
- crushed emeralds
- sitting in the sewers
- sitting in a room between two enormous fires
- fumigating your house with herbs
- autoflagellation
- bursting the buboes

Comment: Is there any evidence of the efficacy of any of the treatments? It seems to me that until very recent times, avoiding physicians was the best way to treat diseases of most types.

Comment: @Jeff, I would say that he efficiency of these treatments would have been not effective at all. I would say the opposite. Bursting the Buboes for example would have made it more communicable.

Comment: @Jeff I suppose if it got smokey enough (from fumigation or fires) the rats in in your home would run away taking their plague-spreading fleas with them... no help if you are already infected tho.